# Change value of another cell via a User Defined Function

Tags: excel, vba, range

The `Function TotalHours()` is designed to accept two ranges. The first range should usually be one row by seven columns (seven days of the week) and the second range is a single cell to accept a value.

I have a problem setting the value for the one cell.

The line I'm having a problem with:

```
rCell.Value = sngOT
```

I get

> "Application-defined or object-defined error".

I tried `rCell.Cells(1,1).Value = sngOT` and get the same error.

```vb
Function TotalHours(myRange As Range, rOT As Range) As Single
Dim sngHours As Single, sngNormal As Single, sngOT As Single
Dim rCell As Range

    sngHours = 0
    sngNormal = 0
    sngOT = 0
    For Each rCell In myRange
        If rCell.Value > 8 Then
            sngOT = sngOT + rCell.Value - 8
            sngNormal = sngNormal + 8
        Else
            sngNormal = sngNormal + rCell.Value
        End If
    Next rCell
    If sngNormal > 40 Then
        sngOT = sngOT + (sngNormal - 40)
        sngNormal = 40
    End If
    sngHours = sngNormal + sngOT
    Set rCell = rOT
    rCell.Value = sngOT
    Set rCell = Nothing
    TotalHours = sngHours

End Function
```

Comment: A Function called from the worksheet cannot change the value of another cell, only the cell in which the formula is placed.

Comment: BTW: `=MIN(SUM(IF(A1:G1>8,8,A1:G1),40)` will get the sum of the normal hours  Then all you need to do is subtract that result from the total sum: `=SUM(A1:G1)-H1` where H1 has the first formula.

Comment: Hi Scott,
Thanks for that. I didn't realize functions had that limitation.

Comment: @Scott Craner: Re 'A Function called from the worksheet cannot change the value of another cell': As stated, that's not a valid 'rule' per se. Though I assume you're already aware, see how to do just that below.

Comment: @Spinner I know of the work around.  I see it as a hack.  I rarely recommend it.  Instead I recommend doing it correctly.  Doing it that way you do not know what is changing the value in that cell, it is difficult to track.  It is why you will see very few long termers here recommend it.  It is not considered proper coding technique.

Comment: @Scott Craner: [a] re 'I know...': Thought you would :) [b] Agree it feels like a hack. [c] re 'difficult to track': IMO, that's odd reasoning (else, the same could be said of any vba that writes values. [d] Either way (and points of view aside), saying 'I don't recommend' is very different from saying 'cannot be done' (especially in a knowledge repository)... No?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Scott Craner, I'm assuming the error is thrown as your function is being used as a UDF (else you wouldn't get the error). Assuming that's true, there is a way to change other cells from within a UDF.

The following does what you want.
Note: I've made other changes and added code notes as to why.

```
Function TotalHours(rgHours As Range, rgWriteOT As Range) As Single
    
''' Declare hour values as doubles
''' Note: doubles declares as zero
    Dim dbTotalHrs#, dbNormalHrs#, dbOTHrs#, rgCell As Range

''' Get normal hours (max 8 per day) and bandwidth OT (i.e. any hours > 8 on any given day)
    For Each rgCell In rgHours
        dbNormalHrs = dbNormalHrs + WorksheetFunction.Min(rgCell, 8)
        dbOTHrs = dbOTHrs + WorksheetFunction.Max(rgCell - 8, 0)
    Next rgCell
    
''' For any given week worked more than 40 hours: All hours after 40 are OT
    If dbNormalHrs > 40 Then
        dbOTHrs = dbOTHrs + (dbNormalHrs - 40)
        dbNormalHrs = 40
    End If
    
''' Round results to 4 places (to avoid floating point rounding issues)
    dbOTHrs = Round(dbOTHrs, 4)
    dbTotalHrs = Round(dbNormalHrs + dbOTHrs, 4)
    
''' Return Total Hours
    TotalHours = dbTotalHrs

''' Write OT Hours to rgWriteOT (via SetOTValue)
    With rgWriteOT
        .Parent.Evaluate "SetOTValue(" & .Address(False, False) & "," & dbOTHrs & ")"
    End With

End Function

''' Sub to set a value in another cell
Sub SetOTValue(Target As Range, Value#)
    Target = Value
End Sub
```

That all covered, important to point out, you could all of that easily enough with formulas:
Assuming your daily hours are in cells A2:G2, Total Hours in is Cell H2 and OT Hours is in I2, the following does what you want:
Formula for Total Hours (H2): `=SUM(A2:G2)`
Formula for OT Hours (I2): `{=IF(H2>40,H2-40,SUM(IF(A2:G2>8,A2:G2-8)))}`

Note the opening **{** and closing **}** at I2:
o This is an array formula. You don't enter the **{** or **}**
o Rather, you 'commit' the formula using Ctrl, Shift and Enter

Comment: Hi Spinner,

I'm more of an Access guy than an Excel guy, so these questions are just to help clarify things for me.
1) Why use double instead of single? (Looking back over your comments, I think I see why. I'm very old school, so I always initialize my variables rather than trust the program to do so for me.)
2) Why use the WorksheetFunctions instead of the simple if-then statement I used?

I've never heard of Array formula's, so thank you for that. The original spreadsheet used a formula that never quite got it right.

Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help :). Re 1) There's plenty of articles around regarding use of Doubles (versus Singles) when working with (what are essentially) decimal values. Main issue is consistency of rounding (which doubles do better). Re 2) For many things (like this example). Worksheet functions are simply easier to do, and just as fast (if not faster) than other methods.