# Paste array in a dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a beginner in vba and I'm trying write a code similar to VLOOKUP but getting all matches and print the results in a column below a cell. the first part is done but I can't paste the results.

I've tried to follow the tutorial from the link.

[Change value of another cell via a User Defined Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70041022/change-value-of-another-cell-via-a-user-defined-function) but I can't paste the whole array just one value and just if this result is an integer.

```vb
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
    
Function PROCTUDO(x, mProc As Range, mResult As Range, mOut As Range) As Variant
    Dim mValores() As Variant
    Dim total As Long, i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    
    total = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(mProc, x)
    
    ReDim mValores(1 To total + 1, 1 To 1) As Variant
    mValores(1, 1) = total
    j = 2
    For i = 1 To mProc.Cells.Count
        If mProc.Cells(i).Value = x Then
            mValores(j, 1) = mResult.Cells(i).Value
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next
    PROCTUDO = mValores
    
    ''' Write OT Hours to rgWriteOT (via SetOTValue)
    With mOut
        .Parent.Evaluate "SetOTValue(" & .Address(False, False) & "," & mValores(2, 1) & ")"
    End With
End Function

Sub Escrever(alvo As Range, Value)
    alvo.Value = Value
End Sub
```

Comment: This sounds like something an array function could do, so VBA is probably not needed. The code you have isn't complete, so it isn't obvious what you are trying to accomplish. Could you update the question with some sample data?

Comment: Also need to add the code for `SetOTValue`

Comment: `SetOTValue` in this code is called `Escever`. But why do you try to use indirect way instead of direct call? You declare `Function PROCTUDO(x, mProc As Range, mResult As Range) As Variant` and call it in `mOut`.

Comment: A FILTER array function would do this natively without the VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Issue1: Return integer.

You have local decimal separator `,` (comma) used. Therefore the string generated for the `Evaluate` method gives a value like 39,25 instead 39.25 (decimal number).

Issue2: Return only one item.

In the second sub the assignment is not a copy/paste action. This set only a single value. Workaround create an array (excel format) with changing the decimal separator to the VBA language. Furthermore add a third variable to the function with the length of the items. (total)

To resolve these issues try this code:

```
Function PROCTUDO(x, mProc As Range, mResult As Range, mOut As Range) As Variant
    
    Dim mValores() As Variant
    Dim total As Long, i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim mTransfer as String
    
    total = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(mProc, x)
    
    ReDim mValores(1 To total + 1, 1 To 1) As Variant
    mValores(1, 1) = total
    j = 2
    For i = 1 To mProc.Cells.Count
        
        If mProc.Cells(i).Value = x Then
            mValores(j, 1) = mResult.Cells(i).Value
            j = j + 1
        End If
        
    Next
    PROCTUDO = mValores
    
    ''' Write OT Hours to rgWriteOT (via SetOTValue)
    ' mTransfer is the generated array (excel format) for the evaluation function, with changing decimal separator to VBA format)
    mTransfer = "{"
    For i = 2 To UBound(mValores)
       mTransfer = mTransfer & Replace(CStr(mValores(i, 1)), ",", ".") & ";"
    Next i
    mTransfer = Left(mTransfer, Len(mTransfer) - 1) & "}"
    With mOut
        .Parent.Evaluate "SetOTValue(" & .Address(False, False) & "," & mTransfer & "," & mValores(1, 1) & ")"
    End With
    
End Function

Sub SetOTValue(alvo As Range, Value, size)
    alvo.Resize(size, 1) = Value
End Sub
```